# How to get gVim's vimdiff to ignore case?

Tags: vim, vimdiff, ignore-case

I am trying to compare two assembly files where one was written all caps and the other in lowercase. Many lines are identical up to case and whitespace.

I tried the following, while two buffers in diff mode:

```
:set diffopt+=icase
:set diffopt+=iwhite
:diffupdate
```

The whitespace thing seems to work well, but the ignore case does not do its work. For example, in the following two lines:

```
            I0=R0;              // ADDRESS OF INPUT ARRAY

    i0 = r0;            // address of input array
```

[the first line begins with 12 spaces, the second with a single tab]

Why? What can I do?

UPDATE: just noticed that in these two lines all differences were ignored OK:

```
                                // MULTIPLY R1 BY 4 TO FETCH DATA OF WORD LENGTH
                        // multiply r1 by 4 to fetch data of word length
```

Comment: Is the transposition of the last two characters in `diffotp` your problem or just a typo while writing the question?

Comment: That's a typo. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to configure vimdiff to ignore ALL whitespaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1265410)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your comparison is failing because of the whitespace, not because of the case.  This is happening because when you use the `iwhite` option, in the background, vimdiff is executing a `diff -b` which is more restrictive about how it compares whitespace than what you're looking for.  More specifically, the `-b` option only ignores differences in the amount of whitespace **where there already is whitespace**. In your example, `i0 = r0;` is being flagged as different than `I0=R0;` because one contains whitespace between the characters and the other doesn't.

According to the vimdiff documentation, you can override the default behavior of the `iwhite` option by setting `diffexpr` to a non-empty value. The diff flag that you're interested in is `--ignore-all-space`, which is more flexible about whitespace. You can change the `diffexpr` in vimdiff to use this option instead of the default `-b` option as follows:

```
set diffexpr=MyDiff()
function MyDiff()
   let opt = ""
   if &diffopt =~ "icase"
     let opt = opt . "-i "
   endif
   if &diffopt =~ "iwhite"
     let opt = opt . "--ignore-all-space "
   endif
   silent execute "!diff -a --binary " . opt . v:fname_in . " " . v:fname_new .
    \  " > " . v:fname_out
endfunction
```

See the documentation for more details:

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27diffopt%27

Comment: thanks for the answer. Your observation regarding the lack of spaces in the 1st line make perfect sense. Now, the question is how can I achieve the `--ignore-all-space` functionality with a simple (maybe one liner) command at the `:` prompt? Reading your function, I guess the if-endif structures are not really required if I *know* what I need/want. So, anyway of doing `--ignore-all-space` from command prompt, working on the existing open buffers?

Answer (score 6):

Following works well for me:

```
vimdiff +"set diffopt+=icase"  file_1.txt file_2.txt
```