# Activating alternate Diff mode via a function call in Vim/gVim

Tags: vim, vimdiff

In a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830171/getting-gvims-vimdiff-to-ignore-cas), I asked how to make vimdiff ignore the extra spaces when comparing. Following the answer and some further reading, I tried to do the following:

.1. Locate _`vimrc` and find the `MyDiff()` function definition. It contains the line:

`if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '-b ' | endif`

.2. Duplicate the function as `MyDiff2()` in `_vimrc`, while changing that line to:

`if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '--ignore-all-space ' | endif`

.3. Open **gVim** with two files in Diff mode, then:

`:set diffexpr=MyDiff2()`
`:set diffopt+=iwhite`
`:call MyDiff2()`

and also:

`:diffupdate`

I expected this to make vimdiff ignore differences like:
`r3=r2;` vs `r3 = r2;`, but it does not. Why is that?

My settings are as following:
`diffexpr=MyDiff2()`
`diffopt=filler,iwhite,icase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems like I found a solution that works, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265410/is-it-a-way-to-configure-vimdiff-to-ignore-all-whitespaces) question. Instead of using `--ignore-all-space`, I used `-w` and now it looks like gVim ignores the differences between `r3=r2;` and `r3 = r2;`.