# Is there a way to configure vimdiff to ignore whitespace on lines that have a non-whitespace diff?

Tags: vim, diff, vimdiff

When diffing two files in vim (e.g. vim -d file1 file2), I want all whitespace to be ignored.

I almost achieved this by following the advice of Adam Katz in this question:
[Is there a way to configure vimdiff to ignore ALL whitespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265410/is-there-a-way-to-configure-vimdiff-to-ignore-all-whitespaces)

That advice causes the diff command to get the -w option, so that it doesn't include lines with only whitespace differences in the results.

If there's a line with both whitespace differences and non-whitespaces differences, then these are correctly returned by diff. But vim highlights the whitespace as a difference too.

E.g. If the two lines being diffed are:

```
File 1: a,b,c,d
File 2: a, b, c, e
```

Then the highlighted diff will be `b, c, e` instead of my desired `e`.

Is there any way to tell vim to ignore whitespace in its highlighting process?

I'm using vim 7.3 (gvim).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diff` operates on lines, not characters or words, so `-b` and `-w` determine which *lines* to ignore. If a line is not ignored, which is the case whenever non-whitespace changes are involved (unless you ignore case or explicitly ignore lines matching some regex), `diff` will always output something like this:

```
1c1
< a,b,c,d
---
> a, b, c, e
```

Altering `diffopt` or even `diffexpr` only affects how Vim invokes `diff`, not how it then processes the diff it receives. Since neither `-b` nor `-w` will change the above diff, Vim will consequently display the same result. Thus what you're looking for is a way to change how exactly Vim highlights the diff it receives, which I don't believe is possible.

Comment: I guess you're right that this isn't possible. At least not in the current version of Vim. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

File 1 = f1,
File 2 = f2

What about removing the whitespace in another tempfile?

```
vim -c "s/\s//g" -c "wq! f2.tmp" f2
```

then

```
vimdiff f1 f2.tmp
```

Comment: This is an interesting workaround. It might work well in some cases, but would make reading / understanding the context of the change more difficult. Thanks!